# How can I make a carousel like this?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel

How can I make a carousel like this with UICollection view?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UICollectionView` has a `collectionViewLayout` which is of type `UICollectionViewLayout`. It is this layout object which is responsible for how the cells in a collection view are laid out.

If you want a layout object capable of stacking the cells on top of each other as in the image you've posted you can either build your own `UICollectionViewLayout` or use a layout which somebody has already created and made available. Examples are:

https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController
or
https://github.com/victor-pavlychko/DeckCollectionViewLayout